# Any way to install drivers for VFS495 fingerprint reader?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, fingerprint-reader

I have a laptop, which comes with Validity Sensors VFS495 fingerprint reader. When I go to settings, there's an option for fingerprint authentication, but this doesn't work when I click on it. It says I should contact my system administrator for help. There's a project for this fingerprint reader on GitHub - [(link)](https://github.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495) - but this one is outdated and supports Ubuntu 18.10, not 20.04. I've tried to install it and I was able to enroll my fingerprint using `sudo fprint_demo` without any problems. But, when I try to login, it says `Could not locate any suitable fingerprints matched with available hardware.`

Is there a way to install drivers for this fingerprint reader? If not, are there some generic drivers that will work for this device?

Comment: Where you able to find a solution on how to make it work on 20.04

Comment: @IsmailIqbal No, still nothing :(

Comment: @IsmailIqbal I finally managed to get the fingerprint scanner working on 20.04! See my answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution for Ubuntu 20.04

The [driver](https://github.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495) I linked above works for this device. I was just using it incorrectly.

There are some things you should keep in mind when using this driver.

- It only works in kernel **below 5.2**. I only tested it in `5.2`, so I don't know if it works in versions like `5.3`. From my other tests, kernel 5.4 and newer makes this driver really laggy and almost unusable.
- Always check how you enroll your fingerprint. `sudo fprint_demo` **isn't same** as `fprint_demo`. The guide I followed suggests you to use `sudo fprint_demo`, which will enroll your fingerprint for the root user. This is actually why I was getting the `Could not locate any suitable fingerprints matched with available hardware.`. Yes, it was because I didn't have any fingerprints enrolled. I only had them enrolled for `root`.

So, here's a step-by-step guide for the installation:

1. Make sure your kernel version is **5.2 or older**:

   `uname -r`

   If it's not, get an older release from [Kernel mainline PPA](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjTtcLDyN3uAhVxx4sKHXICDRYQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkernel.ubuntu.com%2F%7Ekernel-ppa%2Fmainline%2F&usg=AOvVaw2eYd8HIxQ_BAH3jQHl29Tc). You can follow the instructions [here](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/).
2. Follow the next steps. They're for Ubuntu 18.04/18.10, but it works with 20.04 without much modification.
3. The first step is to install required dependencies:

   `sudo apt install libssl1.0.0 libusb-dev libssl-dev libglib2.0-dev libmagickcore-dev libgtk2.0-dev libpam-dev`
4. Run these commands **in this order**:

   ```
   mkdir vfs && cd vfs
   wget https://github.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495_ubuntu/raw/master/Packages/libcrypto%2B%2B9_5.6.1-6%2Bdeb8u3_amd64.deb
   sudo apt install ./libcrypto++9_5.6.1-6+deb8u3_amd64.deb
   rm libcrypto++9_5.6.1-6+deb8u3_amd64.deb
   wget https://github.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495_ubuntu/raw/master/Packages/1704/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
   sudo mv libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0 /usr/lib/
   sudo ln /usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0 /usr/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2
   wget https://github.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495_ubuntu/blob/master/Packages/validity-sensor-setup_4.5-119_amd64.deb?raw=true
   wget https://github.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495_ubuntu/blob/master/Packages/libfprint_0.0.6-1_amd64.deb?raw=true
   wget https://github.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495_ubuntu/blob/master/Packages/fprint-demo_0.4-1_amd64.deb?raw=true
   wget https://github.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495_ubuntu/blob/master/Packages/pam-fprint_0.2-1_amd64.deb?raw=true
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   sudo apt-mark hold fprint-demo
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so /usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcryptopp.so.9 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495_ubuntu/master/vcsFPServiceDaemon
   sudo mv vcsFPServiceDaemon /etc/init.d/
   sudo chmod 0755 /etc/init.d/vcsFPServiceDaemon
   sudo update-rc.d vcsFPServiceDaemon defaults
   sudo /etc/init.d/vcsFPServiceDaemon start
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PetreBoboc/vfs495_ubuntu/master/fingerprint_auth/modified/common-auth
   sudo mv common-auth /etc/pam.d
   ```
5. Now, the original guide suggests to use `sudo fprint_demo`, but keep in mind this will enroll the fingerprints for the root user. If you want to enroll a fingerprint for your user, use one of the following methods:

   1. `fprint_demo`

      You should see a window similar to this:
      [image: fprint_demo window]
      Click `Enroll` next to `Right index finger` and enroll your finger.
   2. An alternate method allows you to enroll your fingerprint from command line:
      Run `pam_fprint_enroll` and press `enter`. Then, enroll your fingerprint.
6. Reboot.
7. In the login screen, when it asks for your password, press `enter` and scan your finger. (this applies to KDE Plasma and GNOME, other DEs may have a different way)

### Troubleshooting

Here are some issues I experienced with this driver:

- The scan hangs on login after resume from suspend/hibernation.

  Solution:
  Open `/etc/pm/sleep.d/ValidityServiceSuspend.sh` with your favorite text editor:

  `sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/ValidityServiceSuspend.sh`

  Edit it so it looks like this:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  . /usr/lib/pm-utils/functions

  suspend_FPS() {
      # Signal the vcsFPService about the suspend/hiberante
          echo " Sending Suspend Event"
          pkill -SIGUSR1 vcsFPService
  }

  case "$1" in
          hibernate|suspend)
                  suspend_FPS
                  ;;
          resume)
                  /etc/init.d/vcsFPServiceDaemon restart
                  ;;
          *)
                  ;;
  esac

  exit $?
  ```

Save the file and try to suspend :)

- Scan hangs and makes the lock screen unusable **after upgrade**.

  This is because your kernel got upgraded. You'll need to downgrade (e. g. by booting the old one and removing the new one) to get the fingerprint reader working again.

These steps were tested on **HP Probook 470 G4** with **Ubuntu 20.04 - KDE Plasma (Kubuntu desktop) and GNOME (Ubuntu desktop)**

Comment: my response for `uname -r` is `5.8.0-41-generic`. There is a confusion in this answer where 1st it says  * It only works in kernel below 5.2. Kernel 5.4 and newer almost unusable*  and then in the 1st point on the steps tell *Make sure your kernel version is 5.2 or older:*

Comment: @IsmailIqbal Oh yeah I meant it causes issues in `5.4` and above because I didn't test the versions between `5.2` and `5.4`. I tested it with `5.2` and I don't know if for example `5.3` works. You can try it yourself but `5.2` works fine for me.

Comment: @IsmailIqbal OK, I fixed that in the answer. I'm using `5.2.0` so you should be fine if you install this version.

Comment: I tried this with the a latest kernal as I'm unable to downgrade to 5.2.0. During the enrolment it hangs and the no responding window pops up

Comment: @IsmailIqbal Yes, that's what happens with the new kernels. I had the same issues too but then I downgraded to 5.2 and it was fixed.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the PeterBoboc user account is gone from github. :(

Comment: @AndreiB It seems there's a fork of that repository available. https://github.com/allankevinrichie/vfs495_ubuntu

Comment: https://github.com/ryantrinkle/vfs495 has the necessary files